# Using Respect/Validation in another language

Tags: php, validation, translation, respect-validation

I want to use the Respect/Validation library in PHP. I know how to use it but currently I'm using it in a project in German language and of course, I also want the error messages in German.

For language translation, there is a [section](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/tree/master/docs#message-localization) in the documentation but I don't really get it and I did not found any answer yet.

They're talking about a translator that should handle the translation of the messages. As a second parameter they're giving "gettext" but I don't know what this should be and how this should handle the translation.

Can anybody explain me how this works?

Comment: Maybe [this tutorial](https://lingohub.com/blog/2013/07/php-internationalization-with-gettext-tutorial/) could help you.

Answer (score 3):

[Respect/Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) won't do the translation for you, you should use a different project, library or function to do that. It won't leave you empty handed though, as the documentation states.

First, you should try to understand how [translation libraries work (such as `gettext()`)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) and then read [PHP documentation on Callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). Then it is a matter of choosing a library, creating the translations and calling `setParam('translator', 'callable')` method on the exception instance.

A quick introduction to your problem:

- Translations are done based on a `source`: it can be a `file`, a `database` or something else, depending on which library you use.
- [Respect/Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) exception messages use the same pattern: `{{name}} is invalid.`. Where `{{name}}` will be replaced by the `input` given or the `name` if `setName()` was called on that rule.
- You can see all messages you need to translate under the `Respect\Validation\Exceptions` namespace.
- Usually, every library provide a single function/method to translate a given string. This is the method/function you want to set on the `$exception->setParam()` call.

If you ever translate all exception messages, [we](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) would love to make them available to everyone else.

PS: You could also make this question [on the repository page](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/issues), more people would help and we could also improve the way translations are handled by the library in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed all Exception defaultTemplates property, it works for me.

```
class Localization
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->validation();
    }

    public function validation()
    {
        $prefix = '\\Respect\\Validation\\Exceptions\\';
        $localize = [
            'EmailException' => 'local message',
            'NotEmptyException' => 'local message'
        ];

        foreach($localize as $class => $message) {
            ($prefix.$class)::$defaultTemplates[
            ValidationException::MODE_DEFAULT][ValidationException::STANDARD] = $message;
        }
    }
}
$localization = new Localization();
$localization->init();
```